# netty java закрытие сервера из хендлера

Tags: java, сервер, netty

Как мне в netty выключить сервер из хендлера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать в конструктор хэндлера `EventLoopGroup`, который будет использовать сервер, и вызвать его метод `shutdownGracefully` в нужный момент.